# Logstash splitting and tagging events

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I need to ingest following format json evens

```
{
"test1": {some nested json here},
"test2": {some nested json here},
"test3": {some nested json here},
"test4": {some nested json here}
}
```

I have 3 problems:

- When i make split

  ```
  json {
    source => "message"
  }

  split {
    field => "[message][test1]"
               target => "test1"
               add_tag => ["test1"]
  }
  ```

This tag didn't appear anywhere (i want to use it later in output

- Second one is with output:
  Now i can ingest with:

  ```
        tcp {
            codec => line { format => "%{test1}" }
            host => "127.0.0.1"
            port => 7515
            id => "TCP-SPLUNK-test1"
        }
  ```

I can do same for all split items, but i guess there is more clever way to do it.

- Last one is question related to identifying events, like
  if format is { "test1":{},"test2":{},"test3":{},"test4":{} } then do something, else do something different
  I guess this should be done with grok, but I'll play whit that after manage to fix first 2 issues.

Comment: split is used to split arrays. You do not have an array, so it will not do anything. Also, I doubt you have a "[message][test1]" field, more likely just a [test1], a [test2] field, etc.

Comment: You're right, now testing with clone. I have partial success - i can ingest just "test1" par of event , but it's still 
{ 
test1: {}
}
i can't make json source to move elements to root json,

Comment: If you want to move nested fields to the root you need to use ruby. Something like:  ruby { code => 'event.get("doc").each { |k, v| event.set(k,v) } event.remove("doc")' }